# Listview items to list(Of string)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview, casting

In C# or VB how can I add a listview items collection to a list but without iterating it using a loop?

The reason is I want to improve this:

```
For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
   List.Add(Item)
Next
```

To something like this else:

```
List.AddRange(DirectCast(ListView.Items, ...))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
list.AddRange(listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => lvi.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cast<T>`:

```
List.AddRange(ListView.Items.Cast<WhatTypeAmI>());
```